# Return a list of tuples inside a rectangular range

Tags: ocaml, fold

As a beginner in OCaml, I'm trying to write a function who takes two int arguments (a and b), and should return a list which contains all tuples (i,j) where i is between 0 and a, and j is between 0 and b, order doesn't matter.
The function should be like this : myfunc: int -> int -> (int*int) list
And result must be something like [(0,1);(0,2)]...

I already wrote a function who takes two int argument and return a list between those two. For example, 1 and 5 give me this list : [1;2;3;4;5].
This is what i've done :

```
let rec btwn = fun a b -> if a>b then []
                       else if a = b then [a]
                       else a :: btwn (a+1) b ;;
```

My idea was to reuse this function, and create two list : one list with the range 0 ; a and one another with the range 0 ; b, and then making all tuples with these two lists.
I've heard of List.fold_left/right, List.map but I can't get it work...
Do you have any ideas ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reuse `btwn`, you basically want to implement this::

```
fun a b -> 
  let la = btwn 0 a
  and lb = btwn 0 b
  in cartesian_product la lb;;
```

Now, you only need to implement `cartesian_product`, which is basically two nested loops: the outer loop iterates of elements `a` from `la`, and for each `a`, you iterate over all elements `b` from `lb` to build a list `[(ai,b0)`, ..., `(ai,bj)]`. You then have to concatenate all lists (the one for `a0`, then `a1`, etc.).

In pseudo-code, that would be:

```
R = []
loop for a in la:
  R := append(R, [(a,b) for b in lb])
```

But instead of concatenating, you can thread the resulting list in parameters and intermediate return values to ensure you always only add elements in front, which takes constant time:

```
let cross_product la lb =
  let rec outer sofar la =
    match la with
    | [] -> sofar
    | a::la -> 
       let rec inner sofar lb =
         match lb with
         | [] -> sofar
         | b::lb -> (inner ((a,b)::sofar) lb)
       in outer (inner sofar lb) la
  in outer [] la;;
```

If you don't mind having a local mutable state, a somewhat simpler approach would be:

```
open List;;
let cross_product la lb =
  let stack = ref []
  in iter (fun a -> iter (fun b -> stack := (a,b)::!stack) lb) la;
     !stack;;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
let createTuples (i:int) (j: int)=
      let rec helper1 acc i j=
        match i with 
        |0 -> (0,j)::acc
        |q -> helper1 ((q,j)::acc) (q-1) j
      in let rec helper2 acc p o=
           match o with
           |0 -> (helper1 [] p 0)@acc
           |q -> helper2 ((helper1 [] p q)@acc) p (o-1)
      in helper2 [] i j
```

The code works by iterating through the two given indices 0< i < n and 0 < j < m
; The first helper function creates tuples of the form (0,j), (1,j)...,(n,j).Basically iterating through I given a fixed j. And the second iterate through values of j.

Answer (score 0):

This is very straightforward with `List.map` and `List.concat_map` (for creating a "flat" list).

```
# let product a b =
    List.concat_map 
      (fun x -> List.map (fun y -> (x, y)) b) 
      a;;
val product : 'a list -> 'b list -> ('a * 'b) list = <fun>
# product [1;2;3] [4;5;6];;
- : (int * int) list =
[(1, 4); (1, 5); (1, 6); (2, 4); (2, 5); (2, 6); (3, 4); (3, 5); (3, 6)]
```